# Object spread support with Browserslist

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, build, browserslist

How can I configure my browserslist setup to allow for object spread? My current .browserslistrc looks like

```
# Any defaults
defaults
# If the browser has > 5% market share in the US
> 5% in US
```

When I try to build that I get errors on lines that include object spread eg: `{ ...obj }`

If I change the .browserslistrc to be more inclusive, something like

```
# Any defaults
defaults
# If the browser has > 5% market share in the US
> 0.1% in US
```

the issue goes away.

Is there a more explicit way to include polyfills for object spread?